# Can I use draggable with createElement?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it allowable to use `draggable` in this way? When I try to drag to the `#drag` element, nothing happens, no movement occurs.

```
myElement = $(document.createElement('tr'))
  .append($(document.createElement('td')).text("some text"))
  .draggable().appendTo('#drag tbody');
```

Comment: You can use `draggable` that way and it will work the same as if you would call it directly on an element that already exists in the DOM. Anyway is there a reason why you write `$(document.createElement('tr'))` instead of `$('<tr>')`?

Comment: @t.niese, this interface was developed with JQuery 1.2 and I am trying to update it to the latest version. I didn't write any of the front-end code and I'm still not very good with it, so I'm struggling right now. So I can just substitute the `$(document.createElement('tr'))` with `$('<tr>')`?

Comment: Yes. But your actual problem is not how you create the `tr`, but the `tr` itself. `draggable` does not work with `tr` (at least not cross browser)

Comment: @t.niese, Ah, well that would be an issue then. The guy that wrote the code for the interface coded for the drag function because as I understand it, drag functionality wasn't available in 1.2. What I need to do is to drag a `tr` over to another table. Is it possible?

Comment: There are different ways to solve that. just do a search for `jquery draggable tr` there should be some answers around there. (Sorry I'm on mobile right now otherwise I would have linked to an other answer here)

Comment: @t.niese, no problem, I sincerely appreciate the help. I will have a look and see what I can find. Thank you for the direction.

Comment: @t.niese, I did find something that claims to work. This solution also uses a `droppable` function which I don't have. Can I use `appendTo` as in my sample or is the `droppable` function necessary?

Comment: @NaN , you could go with [jQueryUI sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) . Something like that : [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wq1o1khe/)